# Push/slide menu from left. Need to hide menu by clicking whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WCauA/668/) and I do not know how to fix it, so the user can quit the menu by clicking anywhere in the content instead of only clicking the button. I wan't multiple options, and I can't figure it out?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
    $nav_list = $('#nav_list');

    $nav_list.click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
        $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could catch clicks on the `<html/>` tag and hide the menu:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $nav_list.removeClass('active');
    $('.pushmenu-push').removeClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
    $menuLeft.removeClass('pushmenu-open');
});
```

This requires stopping event bubbling up, so your first click function has to start with

```
$nav_list.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Whole thing could for sure be optimized, but it should give you a start.

Here is the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WCauA/696/).

Answer (score 1):

In the script i have modified the same script to have a toggle function for the content area, the area with the text "Slideout Navigation"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
    $nav_list = $('#nav_list');

    $nav_list.click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
        $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
    $content_list = $('#contentpane');
    $content_list.click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
        $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');

    });
});
</script>
```

The below is the change done to HTML page. I have added a div for the content so clicking on it can be checked through the script

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="main">
        <section class="buttonset">
            <div id="nav_list">Menu</div>
        </section>

    <section class="content">
    <div id="contentpane">
      <h1>Slideout Navigation</h1>
      <p>

      </p>
      </div>
    </section><!-- End Content -->
      </div><!-- End Main -->
</div><!-- End Container -->
```